# Delvik or Dalvik?

Tags: android, dalvik

The Android's VM is called 'Dalvik' on its offical site, but I found the name 'Delvik' has also been used with Android's VM in some forums and kind of articles. So could someone helps me to figure out what's 'Delvik'? it's just a miss spelling or something else? 
Thanks very much:).

Comment: It's a typo on their part. It's Dalvik.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Delvik* is a typo. The VM is called *Dalvik*. A google search on *Dalvik* returns 4.5M+ results. *Delvik* turns out only a few thousand, with all the programming-related ones I could see on the first pages either pointing to *Dalvik* or to forum posts with typos.

Oh, and this SO thread is now #4 in the google search for *Delvik*. Quite telling!